# How to add flask autoindex in an html page

Tags: python, flask, flask-autoindex

I want to insert an AutoIndex inside a HTML page with more content..Something like this

```
<html>
<body>
//HTML Content here like IMG, DIV, Table
// Autoindex here
</body>
</html>
```

I am using autoindex like this, but it covers whole page

```
import os.path
from flask import Flask
from flask_autoindex import AutoIndex


app = Flask(__name__)

return AutoIndex(app, browse_root='templates/computer1')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Looks like you could try manually putting the result of `AutoIndex.render_autoindex()` into your template

Comment: @Felk Can you tell me how, by writing a short code? I am still learning Flask, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed this by doing the following:

Create your customized `.html` template

```
# mytemplate.html
{% extends '__autoindex__/autoindex.html' %}

{% block meta %}
  {{ super() }}
  <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" />
    <!-- Here you can specify your own .css -->
{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
  <div style="width: 500px; margin: 30px auto;">
    <h2>My Application</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

(This is the template shown in the [docs](https://flask-autoindex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#redesigning-the-template), you can customize this)

And in python, in order to run AutoIndex on that template:

```
# faicustom.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_autoindex import AutoIndex
app = Flask(__name__)

spath = "/" # Update your own starting directory here, or leave "/" for parent directory

files_index = AutoIndex(app, browse_root=spath, add_url_rules=False)

@app.route('/files')
@app.route('/files/<path:path>')
def autoindex(path='.'):
    return files_index.render_autoindex(path, template='mytemplate.html')
    # Here is where you specify your template

# And if you want:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Then start the flask app and should be able to run AutoIndex on your own custom site (in this case at `/files`)

For more info on the `render_autoindex` function, check the [commented source code](https://github.com/general03/flask-autoindex/blob/master/flask_autoindex/__init__.py#L85)